# error 'not found' in heroku deploy with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, heroku, npm

I'm trying to build an Angular project in Heroku. The build is finished, but the page shows me a 'not found' error. What is the problem? Why doesn't it work? Locally the project works, but on Heroku it doesn't.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.13
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > fsevents@1.2.12 install /tmp/build_c45a39e7/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
       > node-gyp rebuild
       
       make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_c45a39e7/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build'
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/.node
         COPY Release/.node
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_c45a39e7/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build'
       
       > fsevents@1.2.12 install /tmp/build_c45a39e7/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
       > node-gyp rebuild
       
       make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_c45a39e7/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents/build'
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/.node
         COPY Release/.node
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_c45a39e7/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents/build'
       
       > core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /tmp/build_c45a39e7/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /tmp/build_c45a39e7/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > @angular/cli@9.1.3 postinstall /tmp/build_c45a39e7/node_modules/@angular/cli
       > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
       
       added 1553 packages in 47.209s
       
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > frontend@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_c45a39e7
       > ng build --prod
       
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/core/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router/testing : es2015 as esm2015
       Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
       ES5 bundle generation complete.
       
       chunk {2} polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js (polyfills) 36.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {3} polyfills-es5.9e286f6d9247438cbb02.js (polyfills-es5) 129 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {0} runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
       chunk {0} runtime-es5.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
       chunk {1} main-es2015.ab9bb9bb1071c1c56fd4.js (main) 3.45 MB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {1} main-es5.ab9bb9bb1071c1c56fd4.js (main) 3.52 MB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {4} styles.e51a067d2fd89a543ce8.css (styles) 30.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
       Date: 2021-05-15T13:31:07.869Z - Hash: ac2c339af714b72bab1e - Time: 154098ms
WARNING in budgets: Exceeded maximum budget for initial-es2015. Budget 2 MB was not met by 1.51 MB with a total of 3.51 MB.
WARNING in budgets: Exceeded maximum budget for initial-es5. Budget 2 MB was not met by 1.68 MB with a total of 3.68 MB.
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 998 packages and audited 556 packages in 17.985s
       
       26 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 43 vulnerabilities (8 low, 24 moderate, 11 high)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 306.3M
-----> Launching...
 !     Warning: Your slug size (306 MB) exceeds our soft limit (300 MB) which may affect boot time.
       Released v4
       https://seismic-energy-retrofit.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

That's my package.json file:
**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.3",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^2.4.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "mathjs": "^7.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.71",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.3",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

That's my server.js file:
**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/frontend'));
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+
'/dist/frontend/index.html'));});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

That's my git link of my project:
https://github.com/Vallo22/ser_deploy

Comment: Could you move all your `devDependencies` to the `dependencies` section and try again? Heroku won't install your `devDependencies`

Comment: @eko I added them and tried again, but still `not found`